# Azure Template for Elastic 5.x

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-rm-template

I cannot find azure template for the elasticstack version 5.x ?

Does the azure template published for elastic 5.x ?

Answer (score 2):

You could find the template on [GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace).

This repository consists of:

[src/mainTemplate.json](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace/blob/master/src/mainTemplate.json) - The main Azure Resource Management (ARM) template. The template itself is composed of many nested linked templates with the main template acting as the entry point.

Comment: @user2883376 You also could create elasticstack on Azure Portal, then click `Automation option`, you also could find the template.